# cannot sendmail myself from Google Compute Engine

Tags: email, smtp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

It appears that it's not possible to send mail to yourself with [`sendmail -t`](http://mdoc.su/o/sendmail.1) from within a Google Cloud Engine image.  Whilst it might make some sense to block connections to outgoing `smtp` ports by default, it's a pretty big inconvenience when all you want is to email yourself that diff from standard shell prior to destroying the instance.

Is there any way to setup a firewall rule WITHIN GCP/GCE to always allow outgoing mail to a single server on the standard smtp port, e.g., to the MX of my own domain?  I don't want to register and keep reputation with any sort of third-party email service.

(I know I could just open up a non-smtp port on my own server, but then it'll be just vulnerable to potential spam emails after a port-scanning; else, port-knocking is also a possibility, but I'd much rather make changes in my dev environment than on my production server).

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed ports 25, 465, and 587 are blocked for outbound connections in GCE. If you don't want to use third party email services and don't want to use a non-smtp port, the only left option is to use a G Suite domain. However, SMTP relaying through G Suite is only allowed through ports 465 or 587, not port 25.

If you are interested in using a G Suite domain, follow the instructions for [SMTP relay service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491).